# Square of Orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $A$  be  an  orthogonal  matrix  and  $I$ the identity matrix. Is  it  true  that  $A^2 =I$ if  only  if  $A$ is symmetric ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathbf A^\top\mathbf A=\mathbf I=\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf A$, well...

Comment: P.S. Householder matrices (elementary reflectors) are a typical example of matrices that are symmetric, orthogonal, and involutory.